# Searching for Viewable

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, jersey

I just wanted to add Viewable from Jersey to my NetBeansProject. It was a horror...

*1'st approach:*

My web app using the `Glassfish 4.0` so I though just adding Jersey from NetBeans
handy option "Add Library" I found the Jersey 1.13 hoping this will give me a
Viewable in my classpath. Alright, the Viewable is there!

```
com.sun.jersey.api.view.Viewable from jersey-server.jar
```

But during server start no luck...

```
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:Error loading class com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet.GuiceContainer
```

*2'st approach:*

After realising that GF 4.0 is considered to work with Jersey 2.x I removed Jersey 1.13 provided by NetBeans. I downloaded
Jersey 2.x (2.1.0). Unfortunattely Viewable is not part of Jersey 2.x ... :(

*3'rd approach:*

When I failed to use Viewable in my GF 4.0 i go for GF 3.0 thinking that this may solve my problems.
I downloaded server happy the see the solution is close. After start I added "Add Library" Jersey 1.13...
I start the server... no luck:

```
SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private com.sun.jersey.oauth.server.spi.OAuthProvider com.sun.jersey.oauth.server.api.resources.AccessTokenRequest.provider
SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private com.sun.jersey.oauth.server.spi.OAuthProvider com.sun.jersey.oauth.server.api.resources.RequestTokenRequest.provider
```

After some digging I found the GlassFish is starting with :

```
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.11.1 03/31/2012 06:49 PM'
```

And I have 1.13 added .... It something new for me, the GlassFish has Jersey included and is not compatible with 1.13 version!

*4'rd approach:*

I removed previously added Jersey 1.13. But I see error from NetBeans:

```
package com.sun.jersey.api.view.Viewable doesn't exists.
```

What the hell... I go for my libraries tree and see only one Jersey lib is added by default:

```
Libraries -> GlassFish Server -> jersey-core.jar
```

It seems the jersey-server.jar is missing....

QUESTION:
If Jersey is part of GlassFish, why I don't see a jersey-gf-server.jar library in my Library tree and only jersey-core.jar is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing Jersey library can be found in GlassFish directory
`GlassFish-3.0/glassfish/modules/jersey-gf-server.jar` and manually added
to project. Viewable is in classpath, and server starts OK.